# How to add more properties to session from NextAuth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth for user authentication in my Next.js app and I'm looking for a way to send additional user information to the front end via session. I want to send user_.id and isAdmin via callback in addition to the things session sends by default (username, image, email). The problem is that user_.id and isAdmin are always undefined. Can someone explain to me why this is happening. I couldn't find an answer in the NextAuth documentation.

This is my code:

```
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GCP_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GCP_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Email & Password",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Enter your email...",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Enter your password...",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        await connectDB();
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).select(
          "+password"
        );
        if (!user) {
          return null;
        }

        const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(credentials.password);

        if (!isMatch) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.userId = user._id;
      session.user.isAdmin = user.isAdmin;
      return session;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Next.js `/page/api/auth/[...auth].ts` i use the following to update a session. In my use-case after the user is also registered in our DB. This is pretty much following Auth0 API documentation.

```
async function authenticationCallback(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse,
    session: Session
): Promise<Session | undefined> {
    const user = await User.upsertUser(....);
    session.user = user;
    return session;
}

export default handleAuth({
    async callback(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
        try {
            await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback: authenticationCallback });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Callback:', error);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    },
});
```